# Use dictionary keys and values as parameters and append to array

Tags: python, excel, dictionary

I have two dictionaries - basic dictionary and additional, and I want to use additional dictionary data to interact with function and append data to the 1st one.

```
dict_report = {'Id': p_id, 'First name': person_name, 'Age': p_age} #basic dict
iter_params = {'Shape': 0, 'Margin': 1} #additional
```

I have a function which accepts 3 arguments and I want to use 2nd dict value as 1st argument. 
Let's say, in basic language:

```
    def function():
        shape = concatvals(iter_params_mammo(['Shape'],14,19)) #goes to cell value directly
        margin = concatvals(iter_params_mammo(['Margin'], 14, 19))
        dict_report.add(shape,margin)
        return dict_report
```

Should return

```
dict_report = {'Id': p_id, 'First name': person_name, 'Age': p_age, 'Shape': "specific shape", 'Margin': "specific margin"}
```

Can I somehow not specify `shape` and `margin`, but just append new values to dict automatically, depending on additional dictionary size and values, but use their values to create new data?

Comment: What is `concatvals`? What is `dict_report`? A `set`?  What is `iter_params_mammo`? You say you have a function which accepts 3 arguments, but the current definition has none.

Comment: But, it sounds to me like you want something like `a_dict.update(another_dict)`.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga, if I will post my function here it won't change an answer. My question here is how can I access the data inside the dictionary in order to update another one and use values holding inside as a function parameter. I will definitely check your suggestion, thank you.

Comment: Are you just trying to append one dict to another then select a key value pair to pass as params?

Comment: Alice: I am not asking you to post your actual code. Indeed, you are expected to provide a [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I am simply asking you to clarify, because I'm having trouble understand exactly what you are asking, and the code you've provided, devoid of context, makes things harder to understand.

Comment: @Joe, I am trying to select a key value and pass as a param first, then append key and passed data into the basic dictionary.

Comment: But again, I think I *may* know what you need. Take a look at the [`.update`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/stdtypes.html#dict.update) method.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga thanks, will take a look! Excuse me if I seems to be rude or something.

Comment: Thats much clearer and doesn't sound to bad.

Comment: @AliceJarmusch no worries. I understand there may be a difficulty communicating. Heads up, I used the wrong url and have edited to the correct one.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga great that now we do understand each other. Can you suggest anything that can help me pass a key value as an argument then?update() method looks ok, now I need to understand how to combine both parts.

Comment: @AliceJarmusch again, your requirements are not clear. But it sounds to me like you want `dict_report.update(iter_params)`. If that isn't what you want, can you please explain *how that doesn't satisfy your requirements*. It is not clear exactly how your input corresponds to your desired output. Is `concatvals` the function you have been referring to, or is `function`???

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you wanted but here is a rough copy.

`toda` will pull a value from existing dict based on the `key` passed in.

`arba` reinserts the key.

`shimi` will update become the existing dict then update to add new key value pair

```
dict_report = {'Id': 'p_id', 'First name': 'person_name', 'Age': 'p_age'}
kv = iter_params = {'Shape': 0, 'Margin': 1}

toda = iter_params.get('Shape')

arba = {'Shape': toda}

print(arba)


def dict_merge(x):
    shimi = dict_report
    shimi.update(x)
    print(shimi)
    return shimi


dict_merge(arba)
```

Comment: @AliceJarmusch   I just came across this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=U5I-2UZBOVg&index=41&list=PL6gx4Cwl9DGAcbMi1sH6oAMk4JHw91mC_)  the guy is a little corny but his stuff is amazing. This clip covers zipping and sorting dictionaries. I think it is relevant to this

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what function you want to create or parameters, but as far as I can tell you just want to merge a dictionary and return it otherwise, so, here's that:

```
dict_report = {'Id': "p_id", 'First name': "person_name", 'Age': "p_age"} #basic dict
iter_params = {'Shape': 0, 'Margin': 1}

def func(d1,d2,arg3):
    for k,v in d2.items():
        #perform function on v
        #e.g. v += 1 or whatever you want
        #add to dict_report
        d1[k] = v
    return d1

dict_report = func(dict_report,iter_params,"3rd parameter?")
print (dict_report)
```

prints:

```
{'Id': 'p_id', 'Shape': 0, 'First name': 'person_name', 'Margin': 1, 'Age': 'p_age'}
```